# dotnet core program.cs behaves differently - Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I would like to ask on why the >dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration

behaves differently on these 2 program.cs code

Code 1:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

Code 2

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

With Code-1, I am able to run *>**dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration*** without an error. Using the PackageManager Console> ***add-migration Initial Migration*** No Error as well.

But with Code-2, I am having an Error on both Pakckage Manager Console and command prompt. Here is the error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to the project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional patterns supported at design time.

As I understand it, both codes basically doing the same thing.

Comment: I just got new information: I think that the add-migation or the dotnet ef migrations command calls the **BuildWebHost** method in the program.cs file. So when I change the method name in Code-2, this is the error I got: PM> Add-Migration initialmigration
An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider.  I think, that the migration command needs an  IWebHost provided by the _build_ command to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convention changed between ASP.NET Core 2.0 and 2.1.

In 2.1, the static method is supposed to return the `IWebHostBuilder` (for tooling reasons).

However, you will need the version of `dotnet ef` that ships as part of the 2.1.300 SDKs (only a release candidate is available at the time of writing) instead of the one currently shipping as CLI tool reference (`DotNetCliToolReference` in the project file).

This was an issue for the SPA templates that were updated in between releases which now follow the new convention but are targeting 2.0 - https://github.com/aspnet/templating/issues/442.

You can easily change your code to be similar to the `Code 1` example you provided or update to the RC version of the tooling that is available at the time of writing.

Comment: Yup. You are right. For now will be using the code similar to Code1. Will wait for the official release of 2.1.3